# Использование переменных из другого класса Java

Tags: java, ооп

Есть код

```
public class A {

    int x;
    String phrase;

    public A(String phrase) {

        this.phrase = phrase;

    }


    public int get_x() {

        return this.x;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A main_class = new A("Hello");

        System.out.println(main_class.phrase);
 

        main_class.init_vars();

    }


    int init_vars() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter X");
        x = sc.nextInt();

        return x;

    }


       
}


class B extends A {

    int y = 23;

    public B(String phrase) {
        super(phrase);
    }


    void sum() {

        System.out.println(x+y);

    }


}
```

Цель такая: Вызов функции `init_var()`, ввести данные в переменную с клавиатуры, затем сложить это число с переменной `y` другого класса `B`, однако числа не складываются, также пробовал

```
   void sum() {

        System.out.println(init_vars()+y);

    }
```

Но тут происходит ввод числа дважды, что логично. Да и подход не особо красивый.
.

Comment: ваша цель ясна, непонятен ваш вопрос.

Comment: Чуток подкорректировал. Дело в том, что числа не складываются исходя из моего кода и если кто может помочь.

Comment: я не вижу у вас никакого сложения каких либо чисел в коде. Я вижу, чт вы что то считываете, но вы же ничего не складываете.

Comment: я так понял, вам нужно создавать класс B, вместо A `B main_class = new B("Hello");` ? И после вызывать `main_class.sum()`

Comment: Сложение происходит во втором классе B, в методе sum(). System.out.println(x+y), X переменная класса A, Y переменная класса B.

Comment: Выложите ответ, я отмечу его как решением. Спасибо, я примерно так делал, но видимо где-то пропускал что-то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я так понял, вам нужно создавать класс `B`, вместо `A`,

```
B main_class = new B("Hello");
```

И после вызывать

```
main_class.sum()
```